# How to correctly configure typeRoots option?

Tags: typescript

I've got a strangely shaped yarn monorepo. Here's how it looks:

```
monorepo root
├── frontend
│   ├── dashboard <-- not a yarn workspace
│   |   ├── src
│   |   ├── node_modules
│   |   ├── tsconfig.json
├── node_modules <-- hoisted by yarn
├── packages
│   ├── other typescript project <-- yarn workspace
│   |   ├── tsconfig.json
│   |   ├── node_modules
```

I've configured all `tsconfig.json` files to have this setting:

```
compilerOptions: {
  "typeRoots": [
     "./node_modules/@types/"
   ]
}
```

I've also got `exclude` configured:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "../../node_modules/**/*"
  ]
```

When I'm inside frontend/dashboard and I run `tsc`, I'm getting the following output:

```
node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3088:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.

3088         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3100:14
    3100         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'LibraryManagedAttributes' was also declared here.
```

I don't understand why Typescript is climbing outside of the `typeRoots` directories?

Comment: Does adding node_modules to "exclude" affect typeRoots? Almost every tsconfig I've seen has modules excluded.

Comment: Forgot to mention I have exclude configured. I've updated the question to reflect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in TypeScript 5.1 ([announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-1/#explicit-typeroots-disables-upward-walks-for-node_modules-types)):

> Explicit typeRoots Disables Upward Walks for node_modules/@types
>
> Previously, when the typeRoots option was specified in a tsconfig.json but resolution to any typeRoots directories had failed, TypeScript would still continue walking up parent directories, trying to resolve packages within each parent’s node_modules/@types folder.
>
> This behavior could prompt excessive look-ups and has been disabled in TypeScript 5.1.